# HTML Email Nightmare

Tags: html, email, outlook, newsletter

Trying to code for Outlook and I want to cry. I have no idea how to test or figure out where it's going wrong. But it looks awful in Outlook and fine everywhere else. I've already spent 5 hours trying to re-work it with some success, but none of the padding or spacing is maintained in the logo header area or the right sidebar.

Any help would be BEYOND appreciated: http://cdpn.io/GAzqh

Thank you, thank you, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like outlook html rendering is powered by Microsoft Word http://www.howto-outlook.com/faq/wordhtml.htm. There are some tips in the link that talk about how to work around the issues.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the widths on your cells. Outlook doesn't know how wide to make them.

Your header code should look something like this. I simplified it a bit for you:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td width="40%" align="center" valign="top" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 25px">
      <img align="left" alt="MD Logistics" border="0" width="167" src="http://www.mdlogistics.com/emailassets/logo.png" title="MD Logistics"/>
    </td>
    <td width="60%" align="right" valign="center" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-right:25px;">
      <img src="http://www.mdlogistics.com/emailassets/linkedin.jpg"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <img src="http://www.mdlogistics.com/emailassets/facebook.jpg"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <img src="http://www.mdlogistics.com/emailassets/youtube.jpg"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <img src="http://www.mdlogistics.com/emailassets/twitter.jpg" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Because you have ample space for the social icons, I just put them inline. You could keep them in cells though, but it was more code to do it that way.